# Whats wrong with this INSERT query?

Tags: php, mysql

Heres my create query, works just fine...

```
$pages = "CREATE TABLE pages (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id), name VARCHAR(255), content TEXT, description VARCHAR(255), banner VARCHAR(255), headercol INT, headerdisplay INT, type INT, headersort INT, category INT, footercol INT, footerdisplay INT, footersort INT)";
mysqli_query($dbc, $pages) or die('Error querying database5');
```

Heres my insert query, returns error...

```
$jewelry = "INSERT INTO pages (name, description, banner, headerdisplay, type, headersort, category) VALUES ('Jewelry', 'A collection of vintage and contemporary jewelry', 'uploads/banners/jewelry.png', 1, 2, 1, 0)";
mysqli_query($dbc, $jewelry) or die('Error inserting jewelry');
```

Comment: By the way, i didnt get any error.

Answer (score 3):

You have an unescaped apostrophe at the second column value for description.

You should escape it with backslash, like this: `\'`.

### Update

If you want to insert from a variable, then you should create a prepared statement with [`mysqli_prepare`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and bind parameters with [`mysqli_stmt_bind_param`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

#### Example

OOP way:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO pages (name, description, banner, headerdisplay, type, headersort, category) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param($name, $description, $banner, $headerDisplay, $type, $headerSort, $category);
```

Or you could use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or other database abstraction layer.

Comment: damn skippy... so how do I escape this, and would this be an issue if it was inserting $description?

Comment: @user1621945: using prepared statements will escape all chars that need escaping for you, that's why the update mentions `mysqli_prepare`. BTW: I don't know what exactly you're planning to store in that DB, but using `TEXT` fields should be avoided if possible (each query will create a temporary table on disk, because text fields are deemed too large). Just a tip

Answer (score 0):

Use these two functions while entring data to database and out from database.

```
/****************************************/
/* Encode special chars                 */
/*                                      */
/****************************************/

function DBin($string) 
{
    return  trim(htmlspecialchars($string,ENT_QUOTES));
}

/****************************************/
/* Decode special chars                 */
/*                                      */
/****************************************/

function DBout($string) 
{
    $string = trim($string);
    return htmlspecialchars_decode($string,ENT_QUOTES);
}
```

Comment: it is for to enter data in mysql database.
browser result = `Bobby '); DROP TABLE users; --`
page source = `Bobby &#039;); DROP TABLE users; --`
database = `Bobby &#039;); DROP TABLE users; --`

Comment: fair point, forgot I was testing in browser, just saw all the quotes appear, forgot about htmlentities. But I maintain: prepared statements are still the best way to go